# error "define is not defined" startup Istanbul

Tags: javascript, node.js, ant, jasmine, istanbul

There is a project on "JavaScript" + "Node.JS" + "Ant".

Tests for JavaScript-code written in "Karma" + "Jasmine".

To assess the code coverage using "Istanbul".

The command:

```
istanbul cover someFile.js
```

an error: 
"[path to the file]\someFile.js:9 
__cov_lhpa2MzHG9ur0fWhNQ3HsA.s['1']++;define('some',function(){__cov_lhpa2MzHG

ReferenceError: define is not defined"

Tell me, please, how to solve the problem?

**UPD:**

The code inside the file "someFile.js":

```
define('someFile', function() {

    describe("Base64", function () {

        it('Base64_TestEncode', function () {

            expect( "TXkgZW5nbGlzaCBiYWQ=" ).toEqual( $ws.single.base64.encode( "someText" ) );

        });

    });

});
```

**UPD_2:**

"define()" - method is related to the employee for RequireJS and to describe the modules.

Comment: Source code of someFile.js:9?

Comment: Added code to the text of the question

Answer (score 0):

Install amddefine pacakage using npm and then include 
global["define"] = require('amdefine')
in ur gulp file.

Hope it will shortout ur issue. Worked for me.